# Intel C++ compiler on Windows catastrophic error: cannot open source file "bits/unique_ptr.h"

Tags: c++, windows, icc

I am trying to use the Intel C++ compiler 19.0 to compile my code on Windows. I am using the following call:

`icl /Qstd=c++11 c:\Users\Bernardo\Downloads\HW1_6200\ProjectAmina\WaterPaths\src\SystemComponents\Utility\Utility.cpp`

Even though this code compiles on Linux systems, when I try to compile it on Windows I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\Bernardo\Downloads\HW1_6200\ProjectAmina\WaterPaths>icl /Qstd=c++11 c:\Users\Bernardo\Downloads\HW1_6200\ProjectAmina\WaterPaths\src\SystemComponents\Utility\Utility.cpp
Intel(R) C++ Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.0.3.203 Build 20190206
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Utility.cpp
c:\Users\Bernardo\Downloads\HW1_6200\ProjectAmina\WaterPaths\src\SystemComponents\Utility\Utility.h(10): catastrophic error: cannot open source file "bits/unique_ptr.h"
  #include <bits/unique_ptr.h>
                              ^

compilation aborted for c:\Users\Bernardo\Downloads\HW1_6200\ProjectAmina\WaterPaths\src\SystemComponents\Utility\Utility.cpp (code 4)
```

For some reason, my standard library doesn't seem to have smart pointers. What am I missing?

Comment: `<bits/unique_ptr.h>` is not the correct name for smart pointers. IIRC it's `<memory>`

Comment: In general don't use anything in the `bits` directory. It's GCC implementation specific and not guaranteed by the Standard. It won't port to other compilers and may even vanish or behave differently in the next GCC compiler version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct header file for `std::unique_ptr` is

```
#include <memory>
```

Answer (score 6):

The header `<bits/unique_ptr.h>` is an internal implementation detail of GCC's standard library. It's one of the headers that makes up the implementation of `<memory>`.

So it looks like your code is trying to include a header from the GCC standard library, which works fine if you compile with GCC's standard library, but not when using a different standard library. And that should be obvious. You can't include a header that doesn't exist in a different implementation.

User code should **never** try to include `<bits/unique_ptr.h>` directly, because it doesn't even exist in other implementations of the C++ standard library. The correct header to include is [`<memory>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). The code needs to be fixed to stop trying to include internal implementation details of a specific implementation.

There's even a comment saying this in `<bits/unique_ptr.h>`:

```
/** @file bits/unique_ptr.h
 *  This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
 *  Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{memory}
 */
```